# Gate resistor needed for this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, protection, fan

I'm making a simple circuit for driving a fan based on temperature. Given that the LM339 needs  a pull up (R5) do I need to put a series resistor in between the LM339 output and the gate of the mostfet? The connector X1 is a KK Molex type connector with 12V on it but but D2 is there to protect for reverse polarity. X2 is the fan connection.

[image]

Any other improvement suggestions welcome

UPDATE:

For future reference, if you (like I couldn't) get the power and gnd inputs up for a chip then use the invoke command to force it to reveal these pins.

Comment: You don't need a gate resistor but you probably want a large value resistor (1 Meg for example) from from pin 2 to pin 5 of IC1A to provide a little positive feedback to the fan switches cleanly.  Also you have not shown any connection to pins 3 and 12 IC1 will need a supply.

Comment: I don't think there is a need for a gate resistor, the gate charge is very low so it will charge almost instantly. Adding hysteresis to the comparator would be beneficial so that the output stays on for a while once it has been activated. Here is a [hysteresis calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/rercal.php) you can use.

Comment: I'm assuming it is a negative temp device despite your picture showing "+" in the symbol - in fact all resistors are shown this way!!!

Comment: @WarrenHill good spot on 3 and 12, for some reason Eagle isn't showing me those pins (even when I place 4 of them down) but the part in the library shows power pins. Yes, it's an NTC thermistor - I've used a normal resistor symbol in the schematic for the PCB footprint - it was just faster, sorry for any confusion

Comment: @alexan_e thanks for the link - that's a much better calculator than one's I've used before - it's not critical for this application but might as well through some feedback in